# What is the left side menu called in Android?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-toolbar

In many Android apps there is an option where you see three white lines in the top left of the toolbar, which indicates that if you click it, or pull the screen from the left, an extra menu slides out with more options. What is the name of this type of menu so I can look up how it is done?

Comment: It's a Navigation Drawer, usually implemented with a `DrawerLayout` and an `ActionBarDrawerToggle`. There's an example available on [this developer page](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html).

Comment: Can it be used in conjunction with the ViewPager I've already made for my main layout?

Comment: Sure. In the example layout on that page, the `FrameLayout` with ID `content_frame` is what holds your main content; i.e., everything that's not the drawer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is **Navigation Drawer** which you want. Follow this tutorial to implement this type of functionality in your app

https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

Answer (score 3):

It is called "Navigation Drawer". 
You can choose it as an activity by creating a new one (in Android Studio).

Answer (score 0):

#### Use the Activity's `android:logo` attribute to put a navigation icon in the top left.

Typically, the top left is used for the Navigation Drawer, but we don't have one of those and instead we just wanted to use it for a simple Settings icon that will take the User to a Settings page to adjust their various settings.

This can be done quite easily. The basic steps are as follows:

1. Add `android:icon` to your Main Activity or whatever Activity you want this icon:

   ```
   <activity
     android:name=".Main"
     android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings_white_24dp"
     android:launchMode="singleTop">
   ```
2. Enable the "home" icon in your in your `Main.java`:

   ```
   getActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled( true ); // In your onCreate() or wherever.
   ```
3. You might also want to hide the back icon in the top left and the app name in the top left. You can do that with these two commands:

   ```
   // Disable back icon in top left and hide app name.
   getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled( false );
   getActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled( false );
   ```
4. To handle the click event you just need to capture the `home` in `onOptionsItemSelected`:

   ```
   @Override
   public boolean onOptionsItemSelected( MenuItem item ) {

     switch( item.getItemId() ) {

       case android.R.id.home:
         // Do something.

         return true;

     }
   }
   ```

Worked for us and the end result is something like this:

[image: CNTRAL Mobile™ screenshot]

I hope that helps!